# Perl - "Use of uninitialized value" error when value should be set?

Tags: perl, file, while-loop, initialization

I'm coming across a "Use of uninitialized value" error when reading in files in nested "while" loops. I've cut down my code to the bare minimum and removed filenames/directories for privacy:

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $line_gene = undef;
my $gene_name = undef;
my $gene_chr  = undef;
my $gene_pos  = undef;
my $line_pval = undef;
my $chr       = undef;
my $pos_start = undef;
my $pos_end   = undef;
my $pos_mid   = undef;
my $pval      = undef;

open(IN_GENE,"somefile_gene") || die "Failed, gene\n";
open(IN_PVAL,"somefile_pval") || die "Failed, pval\n";

while ($line_gene = <IN_GENE>) {
   chomp $line_gene;
   ($gene_name,$gene_chr,$gene_pos) = split(/\t/,$line_gene);
   while ($line_pval = <IN_PVAL>) {
      chomp $line_pval;
      ($chr,$pos_start,$pos_end,undef,undef,$pval) = split(/\t/,$line_pval);
      $pos_mid = ($pos_start + $pos_end)/2;
      if ($gene_chr == $chr) {
         print $gene_chr."\t".$chr."\n";
      }

   }
   seek IN_PVAL, 0, 0;
}
exit;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $gene_chr in numeric eq (==) at Xtest.pl line 36,
<IN_PVAL> line 5772 (#1)
```

and then following these `"Use of uninitialized value"` warnings are the correct lines printed out to standard input:

```
6       6
1       1
20      20
...     ...
```

Unless I'm clearly doing something wrong, I can't see why it thinks that `$gene_chr` is uninitialized. What's also interesting is that for every line of the input file `<IN_PVAL>`, it prints the above `"Use of uninitialized value"` warning from line 1 to line 5772 (see above warning), except that this file only has 2886 lines, exactly half of 5772.

Neither input file (`<IN_GENE>` and `<IN_PVAL>`) has blank lines, either in the middle or at the end and both are formatted as expected with the correct number of fields, none of which are empty.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show an extract of the two files that produce the error.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE After you suggested looking at the files (along with Sebastian), I found three of 2886 lines of `<IN_PVAL>` that had multiple spaces separating fields rather than tabs - replacing these seems to have fixed the issue! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$gene_chr` is undefined, then this means that, for one or more line(s) of `somefile_gene`,

```
($gene_name,$gene_chr,$gene_pos) = split(/\t/,$line_gene);
```

is returning `undef` as its second value (or returning fewer than two values, which is really the same thing).

I can think of two ways this could happen:

1) The line(s) contain no tabs, causing the entire unsplit line to be put into `$gene_name`.  This could result from a line which erroneously uses spaces instead of tabs to separate the fields.

2) After the first value, the line(s) contain two consecutive tabs.  This could result from someone trying to make fields line up more "nicely" for visual presentation if `$gene_name` varies significantly in length.

> What's also interesting is that for every line of the input file
>   , it prints the above "Use of uninitialized value" warning
>   from line 1 to line 5772 (see above warning), except that this file
>   only has 2886 lines, exactly half of 5772.

The line number it shows is simply a counter of how many lines have been read from the file.  Since you `seek` back to the start of the file on each pass instead of closing and reopening it, the counter never gets reset.

The line numbers going from 1 to (2 * the number of lines in the pval file) suggests that your errors in the pval file are on the first two lines, which would count 1..2886 and 2887..5772, respectively.  If the errors were later in the file, the counter would be higher.

Also, as a general tip, unless the lines in the pval file are extremely long, I would take a serious look at whether it might be possible to read its contents once into a hash keyed on `$pval_chr` and then replacing the entire inner loop with

```
if (exists $pval_hash{$gene_chr}) { ... do stuff ... }
```

If you have more than a handful of lines in the gene file, this would dramatically improve performance, since it wouldn't need to re-read the pval file for every line in the gene file.

Comment: I would not say it would "dramatically" improve performance. Perl is pretty good at reading text files. It would probably improve performance, but unless the file was huge, it would not make a huge difference. Kind of a catch 22.

Comment: Thanks Dave - you were right. The first two lines of the file indeed had multiple spaces instead of tabs, which explains why I didn't pick them up visually. I guess a quick check using "cut" would have picked this up - d'oh! As I'm fairly new to perl, I wasn't aware of the fact that the line count doesn't reset when you use seek (though it makes complete sense)! The alternative hash version would be useful but as I simplified the code, it wouldn't be possible to use a hash in this case as `$gene_chr == $chr` is not unique in the `<IN_PVAL>` file! Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

"chr" is a reserved keyword. You shouldn't use that for a variable name, no matter thats working.

You should add a line `print Dumper($gene_chr,$chr,$line_pval);` after your split and `use Data::Dumper;` at the top. It will tell you much about your data. I suppose the problem might be in your data files.

Maybe also add `exit if $. > 10` somewhere to exit after 10 lines read from the file and make debugging more easy.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - I had seen Data::Dumper before but after trying out your suggestion, I have a better idea of why it is useful and how to use it. I was unaware that `$chr` is reserved - I will look into this. I would upvote your answer, as it has been useful, but I don't have enough reputation yet! Regardless, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have much to go on, this is mostly educated guesswork. However, with some feedback, I think we can get somewhere. I added this as an answer, since I felt it was too much information for a comment.

### Analysis

Apparently at some point, there is not enough fields from the split to assign a value to `$gene_chr`. That is why it becomes uninitialized. It is this line:

```
($gene_name,$gene_chr,$gene_pos) = split(/\t/,$line_gene);
```

This would happen if there are no tabs at all in the line, as otherwise you would get an empty string, and your error would be about `""` not being numeric in `==`. I.e.:

```
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)
```

Since your error reports lines that are twice the max number of lines in the inner loop file, I would theorize that your `IN_GENE` file has only two lines of data. Furthermore, I would guess that it has a trailing *blank* line, which you have not noticed, and this is what is causing the errors. It does not completely add up, but it's worth a shot to see if it solves your problem.

### Solution

Try adding a check to see if you have blank lines. Something like:

```
...
while ($line_gene = <IN_GENE>) {
   chomp $line_gene;
   unless ($line_gene =~ /\S/) {   # unless the line contains non-whitespace
       warn "Warning: Blank line in gene file";
       next;
   }
```

This will warn you about blank lines, and skip them. The warning (and also other errors) go to STDERR, which means you can separate them from your standard output in STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks TLP - you were right and I found the issue - three lines (two at start and one at the end) had multiple spaces instead of tabs and so `$gene_chr` was undefined for these lines! This also explains why I didn't find them through visual inspection, as they still looked like they were tab separated! I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep. Thank you all the same :)